# Switching to another window if inside inner frame

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

If I am inside a inner frame and there is button if I click on that button a new window will open. Will it be possible to switch to newly open window doing driver.switchTo().defaultContent(). ?

Comment: yes,you need to directly switch at child window.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to switch between frames, you do however, need to switch between windows.

```
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){ 
driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);     
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class IndexOfIframe {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
// I used http://demo.guru99.com/test/guru99home/
        driver.get("http://yourwebsite.com");  
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        int size = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size();

        for(int i=0; i<=size; i++){
        driver.switchTo().frame(i);
        int total=driver.findElements(By.xpath("html/body/a/img")).size();
        System.out.println(total);
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();}}}
```

Comment: Why don't you add some explanations on what the code is doing so it is more useful for anyone that might read it?

Comment: yes it make seance